# "Expected an Identifier" and "Expected to find ')'" for-each errors in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting "Expected an Identifier" and "Expected to find ')'" errors in my code while using a for-each loop in flutter, here is the code at the loop

```
body: ListView(
      for(String item in groceryListNames){
        ListTile(
          title: "$item",    
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => GroceryListPage()),
            );
          },
        ),
      },
    ),
```

Basically, it's supposed to open a new page from a function called GroceryListPage() when pressing the items in the loop, but the loop is giving me the errors above. Here is the entire function:

```
class _ListsPageState extends State<ListsPage>with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Grocery Lists")),
        drawer: AppDrawer(),
        body: ListView(
          for(String item in groceryListNames){
            ListTile(
              title: "$item",
              
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => GroceryListPage()),
                );
              },
            ),
          },
        ),
    );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First issue in your code

The `AppBar` widgets `title` property required a `Widgets` why you are providing a string

> Second issue

To get click event of `ListTile` you need to use  `onTap: () {}` method There is no method name `onPressed ()` in `ListTile` widgets

Try this way

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Grocery Lists")
      ),
      drawer: AppDrawer(),
      body: ListView(
        children: groceryListNames
            .map(
              (data) => ListTile(
                title: Text("$data"),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => GroceryListPage()),
                  );
                },
              ),
            )
            .toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: thank you for the help, but then it says that the parameter appBar isn't defined inside of the first appBar

Answer (score 1):

The error message most likely comes from the code:

```dart
ListView(
      for(String item in groceryListNames){
```

A `for` *statement* cannot occur as a parameter of a function (and the `ListView` constructor does not take any positional parameters at all).

You might want:

```dart
ListView( 
  children: [for (String item in groceryListNames) ListTile(
     ....
  )]
```

Comment: thank you for the help, but this brings another error I have tried to deal with before, which is shown at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61694677/this-requires-the-control-flow-collections-experiment-to-be-enabled-showing-af